# Read APM settings in BIOS from Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, power-management, bios

Is there any way to check what APM settings are in BIOS from Ubuntu 16.04? I tried with dmidecode, without any luck.
I want to know if there are scheduled RTC power on.
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is. you can get bios info from smbios, and dmidecode.
dmidecode will tell you everything about your bios,  and smbios utilities will tell you specific sub components reading from the smbios table.

some examples for smbios-commands:

`smbios-battery-ctl      smbios-rbu-bios-update  smbios-token-ctl
smbios-get-ut-data      smbios-state-byte-ctl   smbios-upflag-ctl
smbios-keyboard-ctl     smbios-sys-info         smbios-wakeup-ctl
smbios-lcd-brightness   smbios-sys-info-lite    smbios-wireless-ctl
smbios-passwd           smbios-thermal-ctl`

did you also seach for ACPI when searching for power management?

Comment: Yes, searching for ACPI or APM just tells me that they are both supported, but not showing the scheduled poweron (I'd like to know exactly what the scheduled time is). SMBIOS doesn't work for me i get error: ERROR: Could not parse system SMBIOS table.